# Mongoose doesn't connect within docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose

I am not able to connect to Mongoose when I run my api (Express) within docker. If I run my api locally, it works.
I have tried switching localhost to the service name. Other solutions online don't seem to work as well.
I'm running macOS Big Sur 11.2.1.
Can someone please help me out? Thank you!

Error

```html
api_1      | [INFO] 13:17:16 ts-node-dev ver. 1.1.6 (using ts-node ver. 9.1.1, typescript ver. 4.2.4)
api_1      | ⚡️[server]: Connecting to database at mongodb://localhost:27017/
api_1      | There was an error connecting to the database. MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
api_1      |     at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:845:32)
api_1      |     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:348:10
api_1      |     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
api_1      |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
api_1      |     at promiseOrCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
api_1      |     at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1152:10)
api_1      |     at Mongoose.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:347:20)
api_1      |     at MongoClient.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/src/models/index.ts:7:43)
api_1      |     at step (/usr/src/app/src/models/index.ts:33:23)
api_1      |     at Object.next (/usr/src/app/src/models/index.ts:14:53)
api_1      |     at /usr/src/app/src/models/index.ts:8:71
api_1      |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
api_1      |     at __awaiter (/usr/src/app/src/models/index.ts:4:12)
api_1      |     at MongoClient.connect (/usr/src/app/src/models/index.ts:48:16)
api_1      |     at /usr/src/app/src/index.ts:31:23
api_1      |     at step (/usr/src/app/src/index.ts:36:23) {
api_1      |   reason: TopologyDescription {
api_1      |     type: 'Single',
api_1      |     setName: null,
api_1      |     maxSetVersion: null,
api_1      |     maxElectionId: null,
api_1      |     servers: Map { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
api_1      |     stale: false,
api_1      |     compatible: true,
api_1      |     compatibilityError: null,
api_1      |     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
api_1      |     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
api_1      |     localThresholdMS: 15,
api_1      |     commonWireVersion: null
api_1      |   }
api_1      | }
```

.env

```html
PORT=7000
APP_URL=http://localhost:7000

DB_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/
```

docker-compose

```html
version: '3.1'
services:
  client:
    (...)

  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./api
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: api:latest
    ports:
      - 7000:7000
    volumes:
      - ./api:/user/src/app
    command: yarn run dev
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    links:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
        - 27017:27017
    volumes:
        - ./api/mongodb_data_container:/data/db

volumes:
      mongodb_data_container:
```

Index.ts

```html
(...)

 app.listen(config.port, async () => {
    console.log(`⚡️[server]: Connecting to database at ${config.mongoUrl}`);
    await MongoClient.connect();
    console.log(`⚡️[server]: Server is running at https://localhost:${config.port}`);
  });

/**
 * Routes
 */

  app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.send('Welcome to ContraPontos1!');
  });
```

models/index.ts

```html
import config from "../config";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

class MongoClient {
    public async connect() {
        try {
            const client = await mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
            console.log("Successfully connected to database. ");
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("There was an error connecting to the database.", err);
        }
    }
}

export default new MongoClient();
```

Comment: Try to use container name in connection string instead of `localhost` like: `mongodb://mongodb:27017/`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have tried that, and I still cannot connect. I will add the error that I get to the question. Feel free to suggest other option, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of localhost use your ip on database configuration.

Replace this `DB_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/`

to this one `DB_URL=mongodb://X.X.X.X:27017/` ( X.X.X.X means your ip address )on your database configuration file.

on your docker-compose.yml file

- Inside of services of api add CONNECTIONSTRING.

```
services:
  client:
    (...)

  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./api
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: api:latest
    ports:
      - 7000:7000
    environment:
      - CONNECTIONSTRING=mongodb://X.X.X.X:27017/     ##X.X.X.X means your ip address
    volumes:
      - ./api:/user/src/app
    command: yarn run dev
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    links:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
        - 27017:27017
    volumes:
        - ./api/mongodb_data_container:/data/db

volumes:
      mongodb_data_container:
```

Comment: The key for me was to add the CONNECTIONSTRING and change localhost to mongodb. There was no need to add my IP address. I also took Deepak Singh suggestion used networks instead of links. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use networks instead of links try with that, also I am using version 3.7.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  client:
    (...)

  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./api
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    image: api:latest
    ports:
      - 7000:7000
    volumes:
      - ./api:/user/src/app
    command: yarn run dev
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    networks:
      - mongodb-app-network

  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
        - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - mongodb-app-network
    volumes:
        - ./api/mongodb_data_container:/data/db

volumes:
      mongodb_data_container:
networks:
      mongodb-app-network:
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same error occurs. I did have to alter the networks: I remove the "-" and added ":" at the end of the line. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: looking at the docker-compose I don't see any issue, How is your MongoDB server is setup, Is it just standalone MongoDB instance? Because error is **MongooseServerSelectionError** Try with mongodb://mongodb:27017/<yourdbname>. So put your db name in the placeholder **<yourdbname>**

Comment: Also try changing **restart: always** instead of unless-stopped